# $stmt->num_rows returning 0 even after calling store_result

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am looking to count the number of records returned by the query below using mysqli / prepared statements:

```
$mysql = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('There was a problem connecting to the database');
$stmt = $mysql->prepare('SELECT id,vcref,jobtitle,jobtype,jobintro,closingdate FROM jobs WHERE active = 1');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result;
$stmt->bind_result($id,$vcref,$jobtitle,$jobtype,$jobintro,$closingdate);
$stmt->fetch();
$totalLiveJobs = $stmt->num_rows();
```

The output is consistently 0

Comment: How many should it return if you execute directly in DB?

Comment: i know there are 2 rows matching the query criteria - it's a thinker

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$stmt->store_result;
```

Should be:

```
$stmt->store_result();
```

Comment: thx for input m8 - i still getting used to OOP style,

I thought i'd done it right already? in the final line of code? trying to assign the value to a variable?

Comment: No, $stmt->num_rows() is calling a non-existent method of $stmt, whereas $stmt->num_rows references the property (which does have a value). See http://phpbuilder.com/manual/en/function.mysqli-stmt-num-rows.php

Comment: Thx Karim - i understand now, (extra kudos for the link too).
It's working just fine now - thx again mate :)

Comment: I know that this is an old thread, but actually there is a method num_rows() in mysqli_stmt class, so you could use both $stmt->num_rows (as object property) or $stmt->num_rows() (as a method). I think the problem was $stmt->store_result; as http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php indicates store_result() needs to be called to get number of rows in the result set (unless this was introduced later than the question was posted :)